# How to get a value from a webpage? Error in the website

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to make a script that looks for the value of the Dollar (I am from Argentina) and prints it.

I managed to do it with one website ("https://www.bna.com.ar/Personas"). However, when trying with other websites I have some errors. 
I used the same code and changed the XPath to the element I want to find.

This is the code to ("http://www.dolarhoy.com.ar/"):

```
    static String getValuacion(){
        String str = "http://www.dolarhoy.com.ar/";
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
        String valuacion = "No se sabe";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(str);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            HtmlPage page = wc.getPage (url);
            valuacion = "Dolar Venta: " + getDolarVenta (page) + "\nDolar Compra: " + getDolarCompra (page);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println ("Error al conectarse. Error: " + ex.getMessage ());
        }
        return valuacion;
    }

    private static String getDolarVenta(HtmlPage page) {
        HtmlAnchor anc = page.getFirstByXPath ("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h4/a/span");
        return anc.asText ();
    }
    private static String getDolarCompra(HtmlPage page) {
        HtmlAnchor anc = page.getFirstByXPath ("/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h4/a/span");
        return anc.asText ();
    }
}
```

It throws the following error:
`Error al conectarse. Error: missing ; before statement (script in https://www.cronista.com/ from (21, 9) to (120, 10)#109)`

I guess it is something in the website that is causing trouble.
I hope someone can help me 
(sorry for bad english)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes to your code:

Change 1: I added a new line here to disable JS, which was causing a problem somewhere in the site:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);  // <-- new line
```

Change 2: I changed your `HtmlAnchor` classes to `HtmlSpan` classes:

```
HtmlSpan anc = page.getFirstByXPath(...); // <-- changed in 2 places
```

You are accessing spans, not anchors.

After these changes I got the following output:

```
Dolar Venta: $ 116,02
Dolar Compra: $ 115,37
```

### Edit

I should add: If you don't want to completely disable JavaScript in the target page, you can instead use the following to allow JS processing to continue, after an error:

```
wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

In the case of this specific web site, the data you want to access is available in the HTML - JS is not needed to access it.

Comment: Thanks men!!! It fixed the problem. The solution was: wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

Thanksss!!!